# Cannot find an assets path when i deploy my app

Tags: azure

So, I have an assets path like this `'../../../../assets/Modelos/bus_stop/scene.gltf'`.. then i have a function that basically loads this path like this

```
loader.load(
      '../../../../assets/Modelos/bus_stop/scene.gltf',
      function (gltf) {
        gltf.scene.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
        gltf.scene.receiveShadow = true;
        gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
        this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
      }.bind(this)
```

this works fine in a localhost. BUT. I deployed my app to azure. and it doesnt work

in my virtual machine my front end is stored like this

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS5jq.png)

and what i want to load looks like this

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq50i.png)

my question is. Number1: can i make a global path to run both local and in deployed mode?
If not whats the path i can define that works in a deployed path but now locally?

Comment: you need to check the path on console, network tab

Comment: Hello @Sajeetharan.. i updated this post with a new answear.